# How to read content of a shared sheet with Google Drive API (v3) ? authError

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, guzzle

I would like to read Google Docs and Google Sheets shared by users with a specific user (myapp) created by me for my application. I have implemented the Google hybrid server slide flow (offline access) yo use Google services on behalf of this user when he is offline.

I store the refresh token in my database and use it to refresh the access token. With the access token I can query the API. For example, the following code **correctly returns** the files on the "myapp" drive:

```
// Get the API client

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($this->clientId);
$client->setClientSecret($this->clientSecret);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
...
$client->addScope([
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://docs.google.com/feeds',
    Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE
]);

// Construct the service object

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$params = array(
    'pageSize' => 10,
    'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($params);

foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName()); // OK
}
```

...**works fine!**

Some of the files are shared by other users to "myapp".

**Now I would like to get content of a shared Spreadsheet:**

```
$fileId = "1GRTldB2....";
$result = $service->files->get($fileId, [
    'fields' => 'name,md5Checksum,size,createdTime,modifiedTime,ownedByMe,properties,shared,sharedWithMeTime,webContentLink,webViewLink'
]);

$url = $result['webViewLink'];
//$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'.$fileId.'?alt=media';

$method = 'GET';
$headers = ["Authorization" => "Bearer $accessToken", "GData-Version" => "3.0"];
$httpClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => $headers]);

$resp = $httpClient->request($method, $url);
$body = $resp->getBody()->getContents();
$code = $resp->getStatusCode();
$reason = $resp->getReasonPhrase();
echo "$code : $reason\n\n";
echo "$body\n";
```

**This code gives an error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException'
>   with message ' in
>   C:\wamp\www\core\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php
>   on line 107 ( ! ) GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error:
>   `GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1GRTldB2KDFGmFZgFST28-MaHKs7y7eqelbzDpdxuJBg?alt=media`
>   resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: { "error": { "errors": [ {
>   "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid
>   Credentials" (truncated...) in
>   C:\wamp\www\core\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php
>   on line 107

authError / InvalidCredentials

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Shared-Sheet ...being shared with the "user" that you are using on the Google api? You know when you right click on the actual document and say "Share..."